# How can I change the size of my textview added programmatically on layout.addview

Tags: android

On the following code, I programatically added the `textview` on the `layout.addview`

```
textView = new TextView(Chat.this);
/*textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);*/
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
    getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.original));
textView.setText(message);
final ImageView imgView = new ImageView(Chat.this);

LinearLayout childLayout = new LinearLayout(Chat.this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp2.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams LPimgView = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    100,
    100 /*ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT*/);
```

I also implemented a menu where a user can choose to resize the `textviews` on his screen by choosing one of the options given.  here's the code:

```
public void createDialogBoxWithRbutton(){
    /*totalMsg = countChatWithMsg1 + countChatWithMsg2;*/

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Chat.this);
    builder.setTitle("Select From the Options");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(values, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            /*for(int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++){
                Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "Total messages: " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }*/
            switch (item){
                case 0:
                    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font1));
                    /*textSize = 15;*/
                    break;
                case 1:
                    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font2));
                    /*textSize = 20;*/
                    break;
                case 2:
                    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font3));
                   /* textSize = 30;*/
                    break;
            }
            alertDialog1.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog1 = builder.create();
    alertDialog1.show();
}
```

But what happen is that when I click an option, it is only the least `textview` on the layout view that is being changed. The other `textview` remains on its size.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple property for set textsize programatically

your_textview.setTextSize(24); // in sp

Comment: i already did something like textview.setTextSize(20); But still it did not work.

Comment: the 2 given snippets are at the same java.class.  What I want to happen is that when a user clicks from the switch case option, it should trigger the textview.setTextSize.  But nothing happens to it, except to the last textview that is on my view.